Stack overflow in Elm and other Issues
Disclaimer: I asked the same question on reddit (link)
I'm rewriting a Haskell app (used by my students) in Elm to train myself in the language and enable deployment as a static web app for simpler hosting. I hit a strange issue: the function runTrace seems to throw a stack overflow error (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded), which is unexpected since the function is tail-recursive. What’s even stranger is that enabling logging in the function completely resolves the error. I’m struggling to understand why this happens or how to fix it. Moreover, when I attempt to run the code on Ellie, it fails to work, even with logging enabled (Exception Thrown in OutputUncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')).

Below is the relevant code snippet with and without logging.
For reference, I have consolidated everything into a single, unorganized file, which can be downloaded from this link.

code with logging:
runTrace : ComputationModel model state input output -> model -> input -> ( List state, output )
runTrace cm instance input =
    let
        runTrace_ acc state =
            case cm.update instance state of
                Err newState ->
                    (log <| "newState: " ++ Debug.toString newState) <|
                        runTrace_ (\trace -> acc (newState :: trace)) newState

                Ok output ->
                    ( acc [], output )
    in
    runTrace_ identity <| cm.init instance input

and without logging:
runTrace : ComputationModel model state input output -> model -> input -> ( List state, output )
runTrace cm instance input =
    let
        runTrace_ acc state =
            case cm.update instance state of
                Err newState ->
                    runTrace_ (\trace -> acc (newState :: trace)) newState

                Ok output ->
                    ( acc [], output )
    in
    runTrace_ identity <| cm.init instance input


The problem isn't with runTrace_ itself not being tail recursive, but rather the accumulator function you are creating not benefiting from TCO.
When you add logging, it makes runTrace_ not a tail call, so I assume (although I'm not sure how exactly) this must unwind the stack somewhat.
This version seems to work just fine:
runTrace : ComputationModel model state input output -> model -> input -> ( List state, output )
runTrace cm instance input =
    let
        runTrace_ acc state =
            case cm.update instance state of
                Err newState ->
                    runTrace_ (newState :: acc) newState

                Ok output ->
                    ( acc, output )
    in
    runTrace_ [] <| cm.init instance input

Your issue with Ellie is simple: the JS initialization code refers to the module named Main, but your module is called AllInOne.

Thank you for your answer! I understand that using a simple accumulator pattern combined with reversing the list solves the issue (that is also how I solved it). However, I find it surprising that Elm does not seem to optimize CPS tail-recursive declarations. What’s even more concerning is that Elm (in my potentially wrong interpretation) doesn’t just fail to optimize them but leads to a stack overflow, even for straightforward (base) cases where no (deep) recursion occurs at all.
